# Python packaging dependencies

Tags: python, packaging

Simple quick question... say I have a self created package called `miscfun` where some module/script in there looks like...

```
# helper.py
import re
import os

def foo(x):
    # Do something with re

def bar(x):
    # Do something with os
```

After setting up a proper setup.py etc.. I can then 'install' my package and load it using

```
import miscfun.helper
```

However, what I discovered just now is that I can also call

```
miscfun.helper.os
```

or

```
miscfun.helper.re
```

to 'use' the `re` and `os` modules! Isnt that weird and confusing? Can I somehow prevent this from happening?

(If this is not a normal situation, I'll gladly explain more, but for now I hope this suffices)

Comment: What is weird or confusing about it?

Comment: It feels unnecessary to have it there... and a bit confusing because now I have multiple ways to get to the same module. Maybe Im overthinking this, but it just felt odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's completely normal behaviour of python modules. Once you `import` anything into your module, you introduce new key in module namespace (which is basically `dict` as everything in python). And any key in module namespace can be accessed or imported elsewhere as usual.

Comment: Well thanks for reassuring my thoughts :) I can understand why it is there, but as I said in another comment.. it "felt" strange. 
To expand on that a little more, I guess this feeling comes from the fact that when you install a package you also need all the dependencies. So... by that you already make sure that each imported module is already there, hence why do you want to access it within the new package as well? But hey.. if it is just a logical result of the way the system works.. then that is fine by me

Comment: Well, you usually don't use package to access also it's dependencies, even if it's possible and rarely can be reasonable.

It really has not much to do with dependency check. [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and `setup.py` are usually used for ensuring dependencies.